# ons-switch の setChecked を使用するとエラーが発生する

Tags: onsen-ui

ons-switchのsetCheckedについて詳しく教えてほしいです。
どんなに試してもエラーしか出ません。

JavaScript

```js
B = document.getElementById("sekasi");
B.setChecked(false);
```

HTML

```html
<ons-switch id="sekasi" onclick="sekasifunk()"></ons-switch>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Onsen UI v2の前提で書きます

https://ja.onsen.io/v2/api/js/ons-switch.html

通常のDOM操作で良さそうなので以下をお試しください

```
const sekasi = document.getElementById("sekasi");
sekasi.checked = false
```

https://codepen.io/sugumura/pen/rNYgaLK

Comment: Onsen UI V2 JS Splitterを使ってます。
記載のコードを書いてみましたが動かしてもオンのままでした。

Comment: valueではなくcheckedで変更できました。codepenに作ったのでお試しください

Comment: ありがとうございます。変更できました！